# Send Email to other Users when User Insert into a database in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a web application in asp.net using ASP.net membership. I have also created a few other pages which users can use to input data into the database, but  I want to automatically send an email to other users when a user inserts anything into the database.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? What approach have you tried? Did you google for it? There is a SmtpClient class in C# (System.Net.Mail) you can use for sending an email - just one solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A good combination would be to use signalr together with Domain Events, and any action that pushes new data into the database will raise an event that can be handled in another part of your project and this will be responsible for sending all the users messages/emails. Check this for Domain events. http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/

Answer (score 0):

A low level solution would be, using a trigger inside the database and stored proc [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the Sample Mail Format how to send a Mail by using SMTP Client class

```
SmtpClient serverobj = new SmtpClient();

serverobj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFrom.Text, txtPwd.Text);

serverobj.Port = port number;

serverobj.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

serverobj.EnableSsl = true;

obj = new MailMessage();

obj.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text, "sender Name,", System.Text.Encoding.UTF32);

obj.To.Add(txtto.Text);

obj.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

obj.Body = txtMessage.Text;

obj.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

serverobj.Send(obj);

lbltxt.Text = "Mail Sent Successfully.......!";
```